# What is the difference between demagnetizing tensor vs demagnetizing factor

Tags: condensed-matter, magnetic-fields, ferromagnetism, nanoscience

I know the first one is a tensor that basically shows components and the second is a scalar. Problem is some references call factor to the tensor and others call demagnetizing factor to the components of the tensor, not the whole tensor. I've also read somewhere that the demag. factor is a special case of the demagnetizing tensor, but how so? This is confusing me a lot. Also, for both cases I can write the demagnetizing field as *Hd = - Nd ⋅ M* where this '*Nd*' appears both, with tensor notation or as a factor. What does each one of these (tensor and factor) represent?

Answer (score 2):

The total magnetic field ${\bf H}$ in the magnet is the sum of the demagnetizing field ${\bf H}_d$ (whose source is the magnetization ${\bf M}$ in the sample) and the magnetic field that would be present in the absence of the sample ${\bf H}_0$, therefore, the magnetic field originating from external currents.

The relationship between ${\bf M}$ and ${\bf H}_d$  is not simple, and the two fields vary from point to point. However, in the case of a uniform external field and in the presence of a special shape (ellipsoidal, including the limiting cases of spheres, long rods, and flat plates) of the sample, both fields are uniform. The most general linear relation among them can be written in terms of a constant symmetric *tensor* ${\mathbb N}$, represented in components by a $3x3$ matrix. I.e.,
$
{\bf H}_d=-{\mathbb N}{\bf M}
$, and in components
$$
H_{d,i}=-\sum_j N_{ij} M_j~~~~ {\mathrm{with}}~~~~~i,j=x,y,z.
$$
${\mathbb N}$ is the demagnetizing tensor. In general, we have to determine $6$ independent numbers. However, a judicious choice of the orientation of the ellipsoid in the external field allows reducing ${\mathbb N}$ to diagonal form. In that case, the linear relation separates into three relations
$$
H_{d,i}=-N_i M_i~~~~ {\mathrm{with}}~~~~~i=x,y,z.
$$

If the geometry of the sample is a sphere, the three values $N_i$ are equal, and a unique constant, the *demagnetizing factor*, is required.